# How to send GEt request to PHP in iOS

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, nsurlrequest

Hi i have problem in sending GET request to a PHP, same PHP works fine when running it in web browser
here are the code snippet of both the PHP and Obj-C
PHP

```
$var1=$_GET['value1'];
$var2=$_GET['value2'];
```

when i call this in browser like http://sample.com/sample.php?value1=hi&value2=welcome
it works fine, but from obj c i could't get succeed 
obj C

```
 NSString *url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://sample.com/sample.php"];
    NSData *data = [@"sample.php" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [req setHTTPBody:data];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self]autorelease];
    [connection start];
```

Please help?

Comment: You have not specified in your request anywhere value1 and value2. What you could do is simply append those on the url as such @"http://sample.com/sample.php?value1=%@", valueString

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you set HTTPBody (by calling `setHTTPBody` on your request object) whilst GET-requests doesn't have a body, the passed data should be appended to the url instead. So to mimic the request your did in your browser it would simply be like this.

```
NSString *url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://sample.com/sample.php?value1=hi&value2=welcome"];
NSLog(@"%@",url);
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"]; // This might be redundant, I'm pretty sure GET is the default value
NSURLConnection *connection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self]autorelease];
[connection start];
```

You should of course make sure to properly encode the values of your querystring (see http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios for an example) to make sure that your request is valid.

Comment: GET request can have a body, and most of the servers supports that. Imagine the case of needing to do a GET request to a resource with a filter bigger that the maxium number of allowed bytes in the url.