# How to query mySQL depending on users location

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c, database

I am working on an iOS app which I need to pull locations from my database that are within a certain radius of the users location using longitudes and latitudes.  I have a function that will determine the distance between two longitudes and latitudes in my php file.  My thought was maybe I could try to pass the longitude and latitude of the users location to the php query then use that data and basically do a WHERE clause that would be if the distance found with that distance function was less than the radius I need to search.  Is this possible?  Is there a way to pass that kind of data form my objective C file to my php file?  I am very new to databases so bear with me.  Thanks!

Comment: `order by function_to_calculate_distance($where_you_are, location_of_current_record) asc having function_to_calculate_distance(...) < $max_allowed_distance)`

Comment: Do you have an option to use PostgreSQL?

Comment: There are many distinct problems here: Getting the location in IOS. Sending parameters along with an (http?) API call. Executing a query to get locations within X radius from a given point. Try to tackly them one by one. This question is *way* too broad now.

Comment: Pass the data from your iOS app to your web app via `AFNetworking`.

Comment: Check out this topic too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716313/mysql-function-to-calculate-distance-between-two-latitudes-and-longitudes

Comment: But how do I get where_you_are's longitude and latitude I found in my Xcode project to my php file?  In my Xcode project I find the users location or the location they searched and a radius they want to search but how can I use that data in my php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you need to send request in post or get method . then get the value from the post or get method . example: 
  suppose your data in a server and your server name example.com then send 
longitudes and latitudes request using get method 
    www.example.com?longitudes = 1000&latitudes = 5000;

in your php file get data that comes in get method

```
$longitudes  = $_GET['longitudes '];
$latitudes  = $_GET['latitudes '];
```

the send this variable in your where condition , then your problem is solved

Comment: This looks like what I need!  I will play around with it.  I just found this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778318/how-to-send-get-request-to-php-in-ios.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Ok I have 1 more question.  For my SELECT statement, is there any sort of iterator I can use to compare the longitudes and latitudes of the locations in the database to the longitude and latitude I got from the GET method?  something like 'SELECT * FROM Locations WHILE distance(longitude, latitude, iterator.longitude, iterator.latitude) < radius' where distance finds the distance between the two points.